# What in the world is .WORLD on the end of a database identifier?

Tags: oracle

Sometimes I see Oracle databases with names like `SOMEDB` and other times I see `SOMEDB.WORLD`.  I can use them interchangeably with no apparent differences.  What does the `.WORLD` part mean?  Does `WORLD` have any specific meaning, or is it just an arbitrary string that happens to be used?  I've seen other extensions also.

Comment: Just since I'm less than 100% familiar with Oracle, and just for my curiosity, care to mention some of the other extensions?

Comment: I've seen other ones that are more specific to our company, but those are rare.  Mostly I see .world

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's default value of `DEFAULT_DOMAIN` setting in `sqlnet.ora`.

It is supposed to be replaced by your organization's domain, but the admins often leave it as is.