# TNSNames.ora entries

Tags: oracle

In TNSNames.ora file I have entries called TEST and TEST.World both pointing to the same port and same SID

what is this naming convention and why is this needed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What in the world is .WORLD on the end of a database identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133154/what-in-the-world-is-world-on-the-end-of-a-database-identifier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .World is the domain to be used by the connection. You can specify a default domain in sqlnet.ora using:

```
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = world
```

which would mean this is not needed. See: http://www.bijoos.com/oratom/ot_199904.htm